# Como pegar pontos de interesse entre dois momentos no tempo?

Tags: php

Considerem que existem dois momentos no tempo, representados no formato padrão (HH:mm:ss).

E considerem que um ponto de interesse é qualquer momento que seja representado por no máximo dois dígitos diferentes ( Ex: 12:12:11 ou 15:15:51 )

Se eu quisesse ir de um momento ao outro contando os pontos de interesse que existem entre eles, como eu implementaria isso em PHP?

Pensei em aninhar três loops for um pra contar as horas, um pra contar os minutos e outro pra contar os segundos.

Ex:

```
    $S = '12:12:00';
    $T = '12:12:15';
    $arrS = explode(':', $S);
    $arrT = explode(':', $T);

    //Horas do primeiro momento.
    $Sh = $arrS[0];
    //Minutos do primeiro momento.
    $Sm = $arrS[1];
    //Segundos do primeiro momento.
    $Ss = $arrS[2];

    //Horas do segundo momento.
    $Th = $arrT[0];
    //Minutos do segundo momento.
    $Tm = $arrT[1];
    //Segundos do segundo momento.
    $Ts = $arrT[2];

    for($i = $Sh; $i <= $Th; $i++){
      //Conta as horas
      for($j = $Sm; $j <= $Tm; $j++){
       //Conta os minutos
        for($k = $Ss; $k <= $Ts; $k++){
         //Conta os segundos
        }
      }
    }
```

Mas confesso que apartir daqui não sei mais o que fazer :/

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: O que seriam pontos de interesse?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "no máximo dois dígitos diferentes"?

Comment: Digitos são qualquer numero de 0 a 9.
Ponto de interesse é qualquer momento que seja representado por no máximo dois dígitos diferentes.
Por exemplo, no momento 12:12:12  só existem dois digitos. 1 e 2

Comment: É mais fácil você tentar explicar para que você quer esse algoritmo do que como deve ser.

Comment: É um desafio lógico que não consegui resolver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O PHP (>= 5.3.0) disponibiliza algumas classes para manipulação de tempo que podem ajudar: [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) e [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

```php
<?php
function pontosInteresseIntervalo($inicio, $fim) {
    $dateInicio = new DateTime($inicio);
    $dateFim = new DateTime($fim);
    $segundo = new DateInterval('PT1S');
    // enquanto a diferença for positiva
    while ($dateInicio->diff($dateFim)->format('%R') === '+') {
        // conta - count
        // digitos distintos - array_unique
        // convertidos em string - str_split
        // do tempo sem os pontos - $inicio->format
        if (count(array_unique(str_split($dateInicio->format('His')))) <= 2) {
            // se tem 2 digitos distintos ou menos, exibe
            var_dump($dateInicio->format('H:i:s'));
        }
        $dateInicio->add($segundo); // incrementa 1 segundo
    }
}

pontosInteresseIntervalo('19:00:00', '20:00:00');
```

Referências sobre os formatos utilizados (na ordem que aparecem):

- [new DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)
- [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)
- [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

---

Também é possível fazer de maneira simplificada com [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) (sem restrição de versão):

```php
<?php
function pontosInteresseIntervalo($inicio, $fim) {
    $timeInicio = strtotime($inicio);
    $timeFim = strtotime($fim);
    while ($timeFim - $timeInicio > 0) { // enquanto a diferenca for positiva
        if (count(array_unique(str_split(date('His', $timeInicio)))) <= 2) {
            var_dump(date('H:i:s', $timeInicio));
        }
        $timeInicio += 1; // incrementa 1 segundo
    }
}
```

Comment: Foi, rodou perfeitamente.